# Making Python turtle commands smaller / compact

Tags: python, command

How can I make my projects code smaller? Here is a huge definition for my hangman graphics.

```
def joonista_mees(valede_pakkumiste_arv):
    if valede_pakkumiste_arv == 0:
        ht()
        up()
        right(90)
        forward(150)
        right(90)
        forward(30)
        right(180)
        down()
        forward(200)
        back(170)
        left(90)
        forward(150)
        right(90)
        forward(100)
        right(90)
    if valede_pakkumiste_arv == 1:
        forward(15)
        right(90)
        circle(15)
        left(90)
        up()
        forward(30)
        down()
    if valede_pakkumiste_arv == 2:
        forward(45)
        backward(45)
        right(45)
        forward(20)
        backward(20)
        left(90)
    if valede_pakkumiste_arv == 3:
        forward(20)
        backward(20)
        right(45)
        forward(45)
        right(30)
    if valede_pakkumiste_arv == 4:
        forward(45)
        backward(45)
        left(60)
    if valede_pakkumiste_arv == 5:
        forward(45)
        backward(45)
        right(30)
        up()
        backward(67)
    if valede_pakkumiste_arv == 6:
        right(90)
        forward(3)
        right(45)
        down()
        forward(3)
        backward(6)
        forward(3)
        right(90)
        forward(3)
        backward(6)
        forward(3)
        right(45)
        up()
        forward(6)
        left(45)
        down()
        forward(3)
        backward(6)
        forward(3)
        right(90)
        forward(3)
        backward(7)
```

Is there some way I can make this smaller, more compact? Could I write several commands into one line maybe? I am using Python 3.3, this is a part of my project, and I would really like some help on this. It's fine if you can't make it smaller... but I just want to know if there is a way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a simple interpreter for a mini language. For example, you can encode

```
forward(3)
right(90)
forward(3)
backward(7)
```

in a string as `dostring = "f 3 r 90 f 3 b 7"`

A interpreter could look like:

```
def interpret( dostring ):
     tokens = dostring.split()
     for command_id in range(0, len(tokens), 2):
             command = tokens[command_id]
             param = int(tokens[command_id+1])
             if command == "f":
                 forward( param )
             elif command == "b":
                 backward( param )
             elif command == "r":
                 right(param)
             else:
                 print("Unknown command: %s" % command)
```

Then you just call:

```
interpret("f 3 r 90 f 3 b 7")
```